# convert array of obj to array of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am learning array filter,reduce and map methods. while doing some exercises I got struct. I have array of object like this

```
var p=[
  {
    "key": "a",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "key": "b",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "key": "c",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "key": "d",
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "key": "e",
    "value": 1
  }
]
```

and this what I did

```
var column=p.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array)=>{
var arr=[];
arr[currentValue.key]=currentValue.value;
console.log(accumulator)
return (accumulator.push(arr));
},[]) 
console.log(column)
```

and I am expecting array like this

```
[['a',4],['b',3],['c',3],['d',6],['e',1]]
```

after first iteration I got this error:

> accumulator.push is not a function

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `[['a':4],['b':3],['c':3],['d':6],['e':1]]` is not valid Javascript syntax, you can never get this as output.

Comment: You are returning the `push` result instead of `accumulator`

Comment: `accumulator.push(arr)` This is a sign that you should use `map()` instead.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice cant i do it with reduce..

Comment: Yes you can. You can also cut down trees with a rusty saw. It's just more difficult than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

## Getting `[['a',4],['b',3],['c',3],['d',6],['e',1]]`

#### Using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

This is what you've used in your code. The problem with your code is that your accessing an index that doesn't exist in `arr`, because on the previous line you set `arr` to an empty array. You don't need to have the array `arr` inside the reduce loop. You should push the value directly to the `accumulator`

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator

```
const res = p.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push([curr['key'], curr['value']]);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

```js
const p = [ {"key": "a", "value": 4}, {"key": "b", "value": 3}, {"key": "c", "value": 3}, {"key": "d", "value": 6}, {"key": "e", "value": 1} ];

const res = p.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push([curr['key'], curr['value']]);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res)
//[['a',4],['b',3],['c',3],['d',6],['e',1]]
```

#### Using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

You can also achieve this same result using a the `.map` method instead:

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
const res = p.map(e => [e['key'], e['value']]);
```

```js
const p = [ {"key": "a", "value": 4}, {"key": "b", "value": 3}, {"key": "c", "value": 3}, {"key": "d", "value": 6}, {"key": "e", "value": 1} ];

const res = p.map(e => [e['key'], e['value']])

console.log(res)
//[['a',4],['b',3],['c',3],['d',6],['e',1]]
```

---

## Getting `{ 'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 6, 'e': 1 }`

You can use objects instead of having an array for each key/value pairs. This way you can assign a value to a key and get the desired result:

```
{key: value, ...}
```

In your case:

```
{ 'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 6, 'e': 1 }
```

#### Using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

You could do this with the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```
const obj = p.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr['key']] = curr['value'];
  return acc;
}, {});
```

```js
const p = [ {"key": "a", "value": 4}, {"key": "b", "value": 3}, {"key": "c", "value": 3}, {"key": "d", "value": 6}, {"key": "e", "value": 1} ];

const obj = p.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr['key']] = curr['value'];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```

#### Using [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Or with a simple [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop:

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once for each array element.

```
let obj = {};
p.forEach(e => obj[e['key']] = e['value']);
```

```js
const p = [ {"key": "a", "value": 4}, {"key": "b", "value": 3}, {"key": "c", "value": 3}, {"key": "d", "value": 6}, {"key": "e", "value": 1} ];

let obj = {};

p.forEach(e => obj[e['key']] = e['value']);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Note that your newest example at the top can be more easily written with `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to loop thru the array and return the new object.

```js
var p = [{"key":"a","value":4},{"key":"b","value":3},{"key":"c","value":3},{"key":"d","value":6},{"key":"e","value":1}];
var result = p.map(({key,value}) => ({[key]:value}));

console.log(result);
```

---

If you want to create a new object, you can use `Object.assign()` and `map()`

```js
var p = [{"key":"a","value":4},{"key":"b","value":3},{"key":"c","value":3},{"key":"d","value":6},{"key":"e","value":1}];
var result = Object.assign(...p.map(o => ({[o.key]:o.value})));

console.log( result );
```

Doc: [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 0):

Your result will be an array of **objects**, not an array of arrays. While you can fix your implementation to work with `reduce()` it is much simpler to do it with `map()`:

```
var new_p = p.map(obj => {{[obj.key]: obj.value}});
```

If you want a single object instead an array of objects, you can use `reduce()`:

```
var new_p p.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj.key] = obj.value;
    return acc;
}, {});
```

This assumes that all of the keys are unique. If any key is repeated, you will only get the last value for that key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values)

Code:

```js
const p = [{"key": "a","value": 4},{"key": "b","value": 3},{"key": "c","value": 3},{"key": "d","value": 6},{"key": "e","value": 1}];
const result = p.map(o => Object.values(o));

console.log(result);
```